# Evaluating Riemann Summation Limit: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{6(k-1)^2}{n^3}\sqrt {1+2\frac{(k-1)^3}{n^3}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{6(k-1)^2}{n^3}\sqrt {1+2\frac{(k-1)^3}{n^3}}$$

I have no idea how to approach this problem apart from trying to convert into a definite integral using the left Riemann sum formula, but I have failed.

Comment: You have no idea except the right one: it is enough to compute $$ \int_{0}^{1} 6x^2\sqrt{1+2x^3}\,dx$$ that is not difficult since $6x^2=\frac{d}{dx} 2x^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By Riemann sum we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{6(k-1)^2}{n^3}\sqrt {1+2\frac{(k-1)^3}{n^3}}
\\=6\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^2\sqrt {1+2\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^3}\\=6\int_0^1 (1-x)^2\sqrt{1+2(1-x)^3}dx
\\=6\int_0^1x^2\sqrt{1+2x^3}dx$$

Comment: May be better leaving that $6$ inside.

Comment: @AndrewLi why ? it is just a useless term yes understand that purpose is to get a precise anti-derivative. But Does Op understand?

Comment: Substitution'll be more straightforward.

Comment: @AndrewLi I want Op to think a bite.

Comment: I understand it better now. How did you determine what the bound was.

Comment: @AsadAizaz do you know the formula for  the riemann sum?

Comment: I do, and if I am interpreting this incorrectly wouldn't a = 1.

Comment: you are right that is why I put both option for you in last lines

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it now. Thank-you for the help and guiding me through it.